# Given only the legs of an isosceles triangle, can I solve for the vertex angle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I think the title says it all.

I want to find the vertex angle of an isosceles triangle given only the legs.
Is this impossible?

Comment: Think of the legs as physical rods connected by a hinge. What if you lift it up and wring it around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the vertices of the triangle $A, B, C$
[image]

Assume $\angle ABC= \angle ACB=\theta$

Thus, the opposite sides will be equal, i.e.  $AC=AB$

Applying the sine rule, i.e. $$\frac{\sin \angle ABC}{AC}=\frac{\sin \angle ACB}{AB}=\frac{\sin \angle CAB}{BC}$$

$$\angle ABC+\angle ACB+\angle CAB=\pi$$
$$2\theta+\angle CAB=\pi$$
$$\angle CAB=\pi- 2\theta$$
$$\frac{\sin \theta}{AB}=\frac{\sin (\pi -2\theta)}{BC}$$
$$\frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{\sin (2\theta)}{\sin \theta}=\frac{2\sin (\theta)\cos(\theta)}{\sin \theta}=2\cos \theta$$
$$$$
$$\theta =cos^{-1}\left(\frac{BC}{2AB}\right)$$

Thus, the angles of the triangle will be $$\left(cos^{-1}\left(\frac{BC}{2AB}\right),cos^{-1}\left(\frac{BC}{2AB}\right),\pi-2cos^{-1}\left(\frac{BC}{2AB}\right)\right)$$